# Does anyone know how to change Oak's parcel script in XSE?

Tags: scripting

So I'm making a Pokémon ROM hack using advanced map, XSE, and some other tools for the process. I'm having trouble finding the script where you actually receive the parcel in Pokémon Fire Red, and its well possible because its been done before.

I've looked all over online and cant seem to find where the script for it is, does anybody possibly know where I could find this? I understand the location number for the script may be different, I would just like to know how I could find it.

Answer (score 0):

The script for receiving the parcel in Pokémon Fire Red is located in the Oak's Lab map. To find it, you will need to use a ROM hacking tool such as XSE. Once you have opened the ROM in XSE, you will need to navigate to the Oak's Lab map. The script for receiving the parcel is located in the event scripts for this map.

To edit the script, you will need to change the value of the variable 0x4057 to 1. This variable is used to flag whether or not the player has received the parcel. Once you have changed the value of the variable, you will need to save the ROM and then reload it in your emulator. The player should now be able to receive the parcel from Oak.